# Getting Bad substitution error in bash code

Tags: bash, tensorflow

Trying to implement this code(https://github.com/kentonl/e2e-coref)
But while running setup_all.sh getting bad substitution error.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Download pretrained embeddings.
#curl -O http://downloads.cs.stanford.edu/nlp/data/glove.840B.300d.zip
#unzip glove.840B.300d.zip
#rm glove.840B.300d.zip

# Build custom kernels.
TF_CFLAGS=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))')
TF_LFLAGS=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))')
echo $TF_CFLAGS
echo $TF_LFLAGS

# Linux (pip)
g++ -std=c++11 -shared coref_kernels.cc -o coref_kernels.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

# Linux (build from source)
#g++ -std=c++11 -shared coref_kernels.cc -o coref_kernels.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2

# Mac
#g++ -std=c++11 -shared coref_kernels.cc -o coref_kernels.so -I -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -undefined dynamic_lookup
```

Getting bad substitution error in line 15.
Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: What's the exact error message? And how are you running this code?

Comment: @EdMorton no quoting doesnt helped. But removing [@] helped

Comment: Why did you remove the parens from the variable assignment? The original script had `TF_CFLAGS=( $( ... ) )` and `TF_LFLAGS=( $( ... ) )`, which works fine.

Comment: The code is actually comparatively fine (the `[@]` is superfluous but not harmful). The problem is instead that you're running the script with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

`[@]` is used to expand an [*array*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) to all its elements. Your variables are not arrays.

Also, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: Funnily enough, the [original script](https://github.com/kentonl/e2e-coref/blob/875d55eb0a1aae80f0379057b39636e5bfba6f3a/setup_all.sh) uses arrays. I wonder why OP changed it.